# Cassandra COPY command never stops while loads .csv file

Tags: csv, cassandra, copy, cqlsh

Hello and thank you for take your time reading my issue.
I have the next issue with Cassandra cqlsh:

When I use the COPY command to load a .csv into my table, the command prompt never finishes the executing and loads nothing into the table if I stop it with ctrl+c.

Im using .csv's files from: https://www.kaggle.com/daveianhickey/2000-16-traffic-flow-england-scotland-wales
specifically from ukTrafficAADF.csv.

I put the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE first_query ( AADFYear int, RoadCategory text,
LightGoodsVehicles text, PRIMARY KEY(AADFYear, RoadCategory);
```

Im trying it:

```
COPY first_query (AADFYear, RoadCategory, LightGoodsVehicles) FROM '..\ukTrafficAADF.csv' WITH DELIMITER=',' AND HEADER=TRUE;
```

This give me the error below repeatedly:

```
Failed to import 5000 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 29 should be 3,  given up without retries
```

And never finishes.
Add that the .csv file have more columns that I need, and trying the previous COPY command with the SKIPCOLS reserved word including the unused columns does the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In cqlsh COPY command, All column in the csv must be present in the table schema.**

> In your case your csv `ukTrafficAADF` has 29 column but in the table `first_query` has only 3 column that's why it's throwing parse error.

So in some way you have to remove all the unused column from the csv then you can load it into cassandra table with cqlsh copy command

Comment: You're right, There's no way to do what i want. I did a java program to solve my problem using two files. Thank you.